# Change list-style onclick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the style of a list element on click to have a black background with white text. When I click another one, I want it to return to its base state of a white background and black text. The problem I'm having is when I click the second list element, the first one retains the style generated in the JS. This is not what I want.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item Two</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the JS

```
$('.menu > li > a').click(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'black', 
        'color': 'white'
    });
    $(this).siblings('.menu > li > a').css({
        'background-color': 'white', 
        'color':'black'
    });
});
```

I know I'm probably just targeting the wrong thing and I've tried multiple ways, but I can't seem to figure it out. I think I have the parent, children, and sibling tree mixed up too. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here it is on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKnBe/4/)

Comment: Note that although your existing code can be fixed, as per the answers below, a better solution would be to define a class in your stylesheet and on click add the class. Then to return the element to its base state you simply remove the class.

Comment: glad you agree with me @nnnnnn :) too bad he didn't see it in time haha

Comment: @Deryck yikes! sorry bud D: didn't even notice. Thank you for a timely response anyway, the both of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect try:

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings().find('> a').css({
    'background-color': 'white', 
    'color': 'black'
});
```

or rather chain it through.

```
 $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'black', 
        'color': 'white'
    }).closest('li').siblings().find('> a').css({
        'background-color': 'white', 
        'color': 'black'
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqN5A/)**

In your code when you do `$(this).siblings('.menu > li > a')` where `this` is anchor tag there are no siblings with .menu class. Instead you want to go to the siblings of its parent and reset anchor tags of their direct descendants.

- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

SInce you are setting the styles on the element, it takes priority over the css property that you have defined for hover. SO switch back to class and try this:

CSS

```
.menu li > a.active{
    background-color: #000; 
    color: #fff;    
}
```

JS

```
$('.menu li > a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').closest('li').siblings().find('> a.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Or just

```
$('.menu li > a').click(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    $this.closest('.menu').find('a.active').not($this.addClass('active')).removeClass('active');
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MrEP/)**

Comment: Cool this is perfect, but this ends up breaking the :hover after I've selected one of the list elements. Any suggestions? :D Thanks again! You rock, rock.

Comment: @duhduhdan Yes it breaks the hover because you are setting style on elemnt instead if you use classes it can be handled. I will update the solutiuon for you.

Comment: @duhduhdan Updated the answer with options.

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish your goal and will also de-select (revert to base colors) a row if it's clicked again after being selected.

jQuery:

```
$('.menu li > a').click(function() {

    if($(this).hasClass('active') == true) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('li > a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.menu li a {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
.menu li a.active {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Cheers - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqN5A/5/) (sry i borrowed part of @PSL fiddle)

Comment: +1. Sorry, I hadn't seen your answer when I posted my comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.menu li > a').click(function(){  
    $('.menu li > a').css({
        'background-color': 'white', 
        'color': 'black'
    });
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'black', 
        'color': 'white'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/rKnBe/10/)

```
$('.menu li a').click(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'black', 
        'color': 'white'
    });
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').css({
        'background-color': 'white', 
        'color': 'black'
    });
});
```